# You can not use the Unpublish feature in the Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

Google API Service -> Marketplace SDK

You can not use the Unpublish feature in the Marketplace SDK

please..

Comment: And your question is? What exactly is your issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

To remove app from the GSuite Marketplace follow this  [Delete an app guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6216211?hl=en):

> **Delete an app as an administrator**
>
> If you don't want anyone in your
> organization to use a particular G Suite Marketplace app, you can
> remove it from your domain. When you remove an app, none of your users
> can access it.
>
> 1. Sign in to your Google Admin console. Sign in using an administrator account, not your current account
>    reyanthonyrenacia@gmail.com
> 2. From the Admin console Home page, go to Appsand thenMarketplace apps.
> 3. Click the app name.
> 4. At the top of the app Settings page, click  Trash icon.
> 5. Click Remove App.